# How do I change the date format of the html I'm scraping?

Tags: python, html, date, web-scraping

I am scraping the date off of a website. The date appears in a usable format in my browser but when I extract the data string from the website the format changes? What is the easiest way to get the date in a MM/DD/YYYY format?

On the website, the date appears as: "12/05/2013 9:26 PM GMT" and when I extract it in the below script it appears as: "Thu Dec 05 16:26:24 EST 2013 GMT". I'd like to capture just the values "12/05/2013"

```
#Import libraries
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import datetime

#create output document
f = open('CarbonPrice.txt','a')

#create soup
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen('https://www.theice.com/marketdata/DelayedMarkets.shtml?productId=3418&hubId=4080').read())
table = soup.find('table', {"class":"data default borderless"})

#Find and record time
try:
    first_th = table.find('th')        
    second_th = first_th.findNext('th')
    if second_th.contents[0] == 'Time':
            td_tag = table.find('td', text = 'Dec13')
            next_td_tag = td_tag.findNext('td')
            timevar = next_td_tag.contents[0]
    else:
            third_th = second_th.findNext('th')
            if third_th.contents[0] == 'Time':
                    td_tag = table.find('td', text = 'Dec13')
                    next_td_tag = td_tag.findNext('td')
                    third_td_tag = next_td_tag.findNext('td')
                    timevar = third_td_tag.contents[0]
            else:
                    fourth_th = third_th.findNext('th')
                    if fourth_th.contents[0] == 'Time':
                            td_tag = table.find('td', text = 'Dec13')
                            next_td_tag = td_tag.findNext('td')
                            third_td_tag = next_td_tag.findNext('td')
                            fourth_td_tag = third_td_tag.findNext('td')
                            timevar = fourth_td_tag.contents[0]
                    else:
                            fifth_th = fourth_th.findNext('th')
                            if fifth_th.contents[0] == 'Time':
                                    td_tag = table.find('td', text = 'Dec13')
                                    next_td_tag = td_tag.findNext('td')
                                    third_td_tag = next_td_tag.findNext('td')
                                    fourth_td_tag = third_td_tag.findNext('td')
                                    fifth_td_tag = fourth_td_tag.findNext('td')
                                    timevar = fifth_td_tag.contents[0]
                            else:
                                    f.write ('Error')
    f.write (timevar)
except AttributeError:
f.write('Error')

f.write('\n')

f.close()
```

Comment: Web scraping [is bad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping#Legal_issues)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have various issues in your code. You should try using [loop](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements) so that you don't need to repeat the same code five times.

And for BeautifulSoup, you can use the function `find_all` instead of `find`, to find all occurrences of a tag.

And BeautifulSoup apparently parses time in a specific format, so one way to do your task is to just parse the string returned by BeautifulSoup.

I've changed your code quite a lot:

```
#Import libraries
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import datetime

#create soup
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen('https://www.theice.com/marketdata/DelayedMarkets.shtml?productId=3418&hubId=4080').read())
table = soup.find('table', {"class":"data default borderless"})

#Find and record time
time_idx = -1
for idx, th in enumerate(table.find_all('th')):
    # Find the column index of Time
    if th.get_text() == 'Time':
        time_idx = idx
        break

timevar = []
for tr in table.find_all('tr'):
    # Extract the content of each column in a list
    td_contents = [td.get_text() for td in tr.find_all('td')]
    # If this row matches our requirement, take the Time column
    if 'Dec13' in td_contents:
        time_str = td_contents[time_idx]
        # This will capture Thu Dec 05 16:26:24 EST 2013 GMT, convert to datetime object
        time_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(time_str,'%a %b %d %H:%M:%S EST %Y GMT')
        timevar.append(datetime.datetime.strftime(time_obj,'%x'))

#create output document
with open('CarbonPrice.txt','a') as f:
    f.write(timevar[0])
```

Comment: BeautifulSoup can also search by the contents of the tag: table.find('th', text='Time')

Comment: Thanks for the additional information, but using that we won't be able to get the column index, I guess?

Comment: I appreciate the extra help on this - I knew that wasn't a good approach but wasn't sure of the syntax on a for loop. Two notes: 1) To get this to run I had to add an extra carriage return after "break" for the code to escape the if loop before defining timevar 2) I was writing the variable to a .txt file so instead of "print timevar" I ended with "f.write(timevar[0])"

Comment: Yes, you can change the output to a file as you do. Regarding the extra break, I'm not sure about that.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do it:

```
>>> import time
>>> date_time = 'Thu Dec 05 16:26:24 EST 2013 GMT'
>>> year = time.strptime(date_time, "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S EST %Y GMT").tm_year
>>> month = time.strptime(date_time, "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S EST %Y GMT").tm_mon
>>> day = time.strptime(date_time, "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S EST %Y GMT").tm_mday
>>> print("%i/%i/%i"%(month, day, year))
12/5/2013
```